# Creating a function in C that quits if "q" is entered

Tags: c

I have to write a function that has no arguments and returns an int value. the function asks the user to enter 'q' or 'Q' in order to quit. the program will continue if any other character is entered.

Comment: You may find the `exit()` function helpful. But beyond that, the question seems unclear. For example, what's the return value supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. i need to create a function that takes no arguments and returns an int value. the value can be used to determine if the user wants to quit or continue. it also requires the usage of an if/else decision.

Comment: @KUMA well you should integrate that into your question. Do you want the function to exit itself, or the calling program to exit depending on returned value?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to implement what i think that you say.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> /* The library that is needed for the function exit() */
    int get_your_char(void);
    int main(void)
    {
            int x =get_your_char(); /* Here you call your function and you assign the returned integer to x */
            printf("%d",x);
            return 0;
    }
    int get_your_char(void)
    {
            char ch;
            int your_value=666; /* Let's assume that this is the value that you want to return if the user won't quit */
            ch=getchar(); /* Here you read the charachter */
            if(ch == 'q' || ch == 'Q')
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); /* EXIT_SUCCESS usually is the value 0(zero) and makes the program terminate normally*/
            else
                    return your_value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>

char key;

int main()
{
    quitAtQ();
    return 0;
}

int quitAtQ() {
    int number = 1; // enter your return number here

    printf("Enter 'q' or 'Q' in order to quit\n");
    scanf_s("%c", &key);

    while ((strcmp("q", &key) != 0) && (strcmp("Q", &key) != 0)) {
        printf("You have entered char '%c', program continues\n", key);
        printf("Enter 'q' or 'Q' in order to quit\n");
        scanf_s("%c", &key); // enter key will be read as next char
        scanf_s("%c", &key); // next char input
    }
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the caller program to exit depending on returned value, I would suggest:

```
int user_wants_to_quit(void) {
    char input;
    printf("Enter 'q' to quit ");
    input = getchar();
    return input == 'q' || input == 'Q';
}

void caller() { // or main()

    // (...)

    if(user_wants_to_quit()) {
        exit(0); // 0 or whatever
    } else {
        puts("Let's continue then.");
    }

    // (...)

}
```